# ASP MVC Linq Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a query like this

```
var errorLogs = db.ErrorLogs.Include(e => e.Inventory);

return View(await errorLogs.ToListAsync());
```

The Inventory Contain a field named CreatedBy
I want to add a where clause on this field how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is on the Inventory table, then it should be something like the following

```
var errorLogs = db.ErrorLogs.Include(e => e.Inventory).Where(el => el.Inventory.CreatedBy == "Sanjoy");
```